# What encoding is this and how can I decode it?

Tags: text, translation, decode, encode

I've got an old project file with translations to Portuguese where special characters are broken:

```
error.text.required=\u00C9 necess\u00E1rio o texto.
error.categoryid.required=\u00C9 necess\u00E1ria a categoria.
error.email.required=\u00C9 necess\u00E1rio o e-mail. 
error.email.invalid=O e-mail \u00E9 inv\u00E1lido.
error.fuel.invalid=\u00C9 necess\u00E1rio o tipo de combust\u00EDvel.
error.regdate.invalid=\u00C9 necess\u00E1rio ano de fabrica\u00E7\u00E3o.
error.mileage.invalid=\u00C9 necess\u00E1ria escolher a quilometragem.
error.color.invalid=\u00C9 necess\u00E1ria a cor.
```

Can you tell me how to decode the file to use the common Portuguese letters?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "\u" is prefix for unicode. You can use the strings "as is", and you'll have diacritics showing in the output. A python code would be something like:

```
print u"\u00C9 necess\u00E1rio o texto."
```

which outputs:

> É necessário o texto.

Otherwise, you need to convert them in their ASCII equivalents. You can do a simple find/replace. I ended up writing a function like that for converting Romanian diacritics a while ago, but I had dynamic strings coming in...

Answer (score 0):

Smell to me like this is unicode?

\u = prefix unicode character

00E1 = hex code for the 2 byte number of the unicode.

Not sure what the format is - I would ask the sencer, but i would try this approach to decode it.

---

found it ;)
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm

Look at the tables with source code. This can be a C++ source file. This is the way you give unicodde characters in source.